# R equivalent of LIKE clause in SQL [using a lookup table]?

Tags: sql, r

I am having hard time wording my question so let me just show you.

I have a lookup table that looks like this:

[image: Lookup Table]

And my main table looks like this:

[image: Main Table]

My desired output needs to be like this:

[image]

Please suggest better way to word this question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `%like%` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, InTheLookupTable := as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1$LookUpVal,
         `%like%`, vector = Value)))]
df2
#   Value InTheLookupTable
#1:   AB3                1
#2:   AB6                1
#3:   V89                0
#4:   8CX                0
#5:   BR9                1
#6:   H89                0
#7:   T16                1
#8:   BR5                1
```

---

Or using `grep` from `base R`

```
df2$InTheLookupTable <- grepl(paste(df1$LookUpVal, collapse="|"), df2$Value)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(LookUpVal = c("AB", "AS", "Q", "T", "BR")),
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Value = c("AB3", "AB6", "V89", "8CX", "BR9", "H89", 
"T16", "BR5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```